# JMeter integer expression expected error in CentOS

Tags: jmeter, centos

I am getting the following error while executing the JMeter script in CentOS. My JMeter version is 4.0 and Java is 1.8. My script is working fine in Windows.

Here is my JMeter command and the error i gets.

```
[root@localhost bin]# sh jmeter -n -t /opt/kpm/src/test/jmeter/reliability/scripts/UIAutomation_Test.jmx
jmeter: line 128: [: : integer expression expected
jmeter: line 192: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Which version of JMeter are you using ?

Comment: Im using JMeter 4.0

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to others. Thanks

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to community. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are fixes for this in last JMeter 5.0 which is released today.

See :

- https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

Install last jdk 8 version and then set this:

> export JAVA_HOME=<path to your jdk installation>

Comment: It is working fine in the Windows. I am facing issue only with CentOS. Is it a JMeter issue or some other issue?

Comment: The issue was in searching for java program, in 5.0 there are fixes for both Windows (you are not affected) and linux in jmeter.sh. So try it and report if any problem.