# JMeter installation in CentOS machine displays errors

Tags: jmeter, centos

I have installed JMeter in a CentOS machine (following this https://gist.github.com/smithbr/f2f19d7c362ef17530aaa7ccfaefeb06) . 
The installation process went fine. No errors shown.
While trying to execute jmeter I get the following fail messages:

./jmeter
./jmeter: line 128: [: : integer expression expected

./jmeter: line 192: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-1.el7_7.x86_64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory

There is a very similar question to this ([JMeter integer expression expected error in CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399437/jmeter-integer-expression-expected-error-in-centos)) which is a bit old and I think that the solution proposed is not solving the issue since now you have available newer versions of Jmeter giving the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52400095/2897748) you're referring:

   > There are fixes for this in last JMeter 5.0 which is released today.
2. According to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) article:

   > JMeter - it’s always best to use the latest version of JMeter as the new releases contain performance improvements and bug fixes in addition to any new features.

So my expectation is that if you change JMeter version from 3.2 to [JMeter 5.1.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-1-released-td5728320.html) the installation process will work just fine

[image]

Comment: I was running JMeter 5.0, I updated to the latest version and it works fine. Thanks.